# Можно ли отправлять свои пакеты через WinPcap?

Tags: windows, c++

Если нет, то какие есть библиотеки для этой задачи?

Comment: [можно](http://www.winpcap.org/docs/docs_412/html/group__wpcap__tut8.html)